# SQL Server will index help here

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with columns A, B, C, D, and E. There is currently a clustered index on A (the primary key, a unique identifier).

I often do selects on columns A, B, and C (i.e. where A=?? and B=?? and C=??). I also often do selects on just A, and other selects on A, B, and D.

What advantage does the clustered index have on the selects that query on more than just column A?

As a general rule of thumb for tables with a decent amount of rows and a UUID as a primary key, should I have nonclustered indexes on all commonly used select column combinations and a clustered index on the PK column?

Note: I use SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Joda Maki - There is functionality on SO called as upvoting. Dont see that you have tried it on any of your 43 questions you have asked. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up

Comment: There's no clear cut rule for this. Yes, those indices might help - or not, depending on what your queries and your underlying data really looks like. You need to 1) measure your current performance, then 2) make a change (e.g. introduce one of the obvious indices), and then 3) measure again and see if you get an improvement.

Comment: Read [Kimberly Tripp's blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) on why a GUID makes a really poor clustering key (and the primary key on your table is your clustering key by default - unless you've already known about this and specifically changed that default behavior)

Comment: @Sachin: you have to be registered to upvote

Comment: @Joda Maki - You are already registered. ;) Try it out once, click on ay of posted answers uparrow beside the answers on any of your 43 questions.

Comment: @Sachin: "Please login or register to vote for this post"

Comment: @Joda Maki - Check if you are logged into the system. The top bar should show your name and reputation.

Comment: @Sachin: It is, but it also asks me to register if I want. One of the most useful things about SO is that you can use it without ever registering.

Comment: @Joda Maki - Yep. Got it. Thanks and sorry for my earlier comments. I did not know if such a feature existed in SO. Pretty good.

Comment: @Joda: You are certainly not obligated to register, but why not? You seem to be a contributing member in every other way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a clustered index on A, you can have only non-clustered indexes on other columns B and C. The columns which you use in the where clauses. This will surely help in reducing the time of query execution.

Remember you can only have one clustered index per table and by default your primary key column will be clustered indexed.

Comment: would it help to have nonclustered index on A and a nonclustered index on B, or would it only help to have a nonclustered index on the joint BC?

Comment: @Joda Maki - You should leave the clustered index on A. Have non-clustered indexes on B,C and D. The columns which you frequently use in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Joda Maki - Putting a non-clustered index on your clustered index key would just be ignored by SQL Server anyways.  The clustered key is included in all non-clustered indexes.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say B and C above, not A and B

Answer (score 0):

A is a unique identifier and the primary key with a clustered index.  That's as fast as it gets.  The clustered index won't help you for queries where you *also* have B and C or B and D, but the reason is that the extra columns are redundant for the query; you just don't need them.  A alone is enough to determine your result set and A is the fastest query you can run.  Indexes that include your other columns will only help you when you have queries where A is not involved.

Comment: say I had a clustered index on AB. Would queries like "where B=??" benefit from the combination column index?

Comment: @Joda Maki: no. If you have an index on `(A,B)`, queries using `A=xx` and `A=xx AND B=yy` will benefit - but **not** queries with just `B=yy`

Comment: @marc_s: why would queries with A=xx benefit but not B=yy?

Comment: @Joda Maki: because of the order of the columns in the index; if you have (A,B), then a query using just (A) or using both (A,B) will benefit - but just (B) cannot - the index is on (A,B), so it cannot help anything for just (B) (each index entry really is a combination of (A,B) - if you're looking for specific A'^s, or A+B's, that helps - but it doesn't help for just B's)

Comment: @Joda Maki: don't know where you're from - but imagine a phone book; it's typically sorted by `(LastName, FirstName)`. With this, you can find `Coehoorn` really quickly - and then find `John` within those entries. But the typical phone book really doesn't help you when you're searching for all `David` since the index is on `(LastName, FirstName)` .....